# Svelte: How to subscribe to a variable in component scope

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am using [`svelte-countdown`](https://github.com/rallisf1/svelte-countdown/blob/master/src/Countdown.svelte). It declares a variable `remaining`, but I can't figure out how to access it outside of that component's scope. I would like to call a function when the countdown ends (i.e., when `remaining.done == true`).

The solution is have is inelegant and prints the promise object. I'm sure there is a more Sveltian solution.

```js
<script>
    import Countdown from "svelte-countdown";
    async function update() {
        ///do things
    }
</script>

<Countdown
    from="2021-05-26 20:19:30"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    zone="America/Chicago"
    let:remaining>
    {#if !remaining.done}
        Available in<br />
        <span>{remaining.days} days</span>
        <span>{remaining.hours} hours</span>
        <span>{remaining.minutes} minutes</span>
        <span>{remaining.seconds} seconds</span>
    {:else}
        {update() || ""}
    {/if}
</Countdown>
```

Comment: Actually, `remaining` is not a promise object. It's just a plain JS object which happens to have a `done` field of type `boolean` which might have made you think it was a promise. The way svelte-countdown is implemented, you can't do much differently/more "sveltian" than what you're already doing.

Comment: The promise I meant is `update()`, which was printing in the `else` block. But either way, you're right about svelte-countdown, and I'll have to find a better solution. Thanks for the reply.